# What's causing 'Error 29001: Unable to authenticate user'?

Tags: 2013-sp1, upgrade, installation, hotfix-rollup

I am running the upgrade tool to turn my 2013 SP1 into a 2013 SP1 HR1 (hotfix rollup 1), but keep getting the following error:

Error 29001. Unable to authenticate user

The log file shows more info, but I'm still puzzled:

```
Action start 10:58:00: DecryptProperties.
MSI (s) (94!E4) [10:58:01:549]: Product: SDL Tridion Content Manager --    
Error 29001. Unable to authenticate user.
DecryptProperties:  Error 0x8007000d: Base-64 decoding failed. Can't 
calculate the length of the decoded data. The data is invalid.
```

I've checked the following:

- Does the user who is running the installer have access to the TridionRsaKeyContainer? The answer was: Yes, but to be sure I ran the following command:

> aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "LINDE\EXDE07C1"

- Is the MTSUser still active? The answer was: Yes.
- Did the password of the MTSUser change recently (or ever)? The answer was: No.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

When you install the Tridion Content Manager, the credentials of the MTSUser (which you specify during the install) are stored in the registry, in the following location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion\Installer\

Here you'll find the following keys:

system_account_domain
system_account_name
system_account_password

For some reason, the value of the system_account_password had become corrupt on my machine.

To fix, I did the following:

- Backup the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion)
- Remove the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion\Content Manager\Version
- Remove the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Tridion\Installer\system_account_password
- NOTE: in my case only the password was corrupted, but you can also delete the keys system_account_domain and/or system_account_name if you like
- Finally, I repaired the installation with the following command:

  msiexec /i {5B6054E3-2406-4EEE-B145-F7165CBE5E9B} REINSTALLMODE=m SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_NAME_TEMP= SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_TEMP= SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_TEMP= /qb /l*v C:\TridionCM2013SP1_registry_reinstall.log

The registry keys were re-created and I was able to run the upgrade tool successfully.